# C# MySqlConnector 6.4.4 LAST_INSERT_ID() As INT64?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, mysql-connector

```
SELECT CONVERT(LAST_INSERT_ID(), SIGNED INTEGER);
```

MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() and MySqlDataReader.GetValue(int index) both return and `object` type. I assumed because I explicitly converted that LAST_INSERT_ID to a SIGNED INTEGER that I would be able to unbox that object using something like `(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()` or `(int)rdr.GetValue(0)`.

However, I keep getting an error stating that the cast is not valid. While debugging I noticed that the type of the object being returned is INT64. Thus, I can unbox the object by casting the value by using `(long)cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

I'm just trying to understand why it is coming back as INT64 instead of INT32?

By the way, my data type for the **autoincrement column is SIGNED INTEGER**.

Here is a test case:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["skimmel"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO test (Name) VALUES (@Name); SELECT CONVERT(LAST_INSERT_ID(), SIGNED INTEGER);", con))
    {
        var p = new MySqlParameter("@Name", MySqlDbType.String);
        p.Value = "Test" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

        con.Open();

        object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Type t = val.GetType();
        long l = (long)val;
        int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(val);
        int i2 = (int)val;  // <-- Error here!
    }
}
```

---

Did some follow up testing and found that the issue is not isolated to LAST_INSERT_ID. `SELECT 1 AS ID` and `SELECT CONVERT(1, SIGNED INTEGER) As ID` also return a 64-bit int through the connector. Going to try to see if I can figure anything out by loading MySql.Data in [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)

Comment: what size is the underlying key field that generated this id? last_insert_id() couldn't return a 32bit int if the actual keyfield is 64bit without truncating/corrupting the key.

Comment: The data type is a SIGNED INTEGER (NOT NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting a Connector/Net bug and getting feedback, I was directed to the documentation. CONVERT and CAST both result in 64-bit numbers when casting to an integer type. Not sure why they don't just do something like CAST(1 As SMALLINT), CAST(1 AS INT), CAST(1 AS BIGINT), but they dont. Since it is returned from the MySQL server as LONGLONG (64-bit), the connector wouldn't know it should be a 32-bit int.

I'm still trying to figure out why LAST_INSERT_ID() returns LONGLONG from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because when the value returned isn't too big then the Convert.ToInt32() can do the conversion (i.e. the value will fit in a 32 bit integer). The cast though is telling the compiler that you think the val IS a 32-bit value, which it isn't.

Comment: My database type is SIGNED INT which should be Int32. I explicitly converted to SIGNED INT in the SQL. I understand that ExecuteScalar is giving me a BIGINT (Int64). What I am trying to figure out is why the MySqlConnector continues to give me the val as a 64-bit value instead of a 32-bit value.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean - that is odd. If you don't explicitly cast it before you return it, what happens?